Theorem 5.3.1 in translation surface book of Masur & Jayadev
I was reading the proof of this theorem in the book and the authors use the following statement in the proof:
why any $SL(2, \mathbb R)$- invariant function $f$ on $\mathcal H$(the strata of translational surface) is $g_t$- invariant.
Where $g_t$ is the teichmüller geodesic flow.
How can I prove this statement?
I am learning the subject by myself, sorry if this a trivial question.
EDIT:
1- The Theorem statement is:
The $SL(2, \mathbb R)$-action on $\mathcal H$ is ergodic with respect to the $MSV$ measure $\mu_{\mathcal H}.$
2- The Teichmüller geodesic flow is defined as:
It has a connection with Teichmüller metric as follows: We consider the $1$- parameter subgroup $$A = \{ g_t = \begin{matrix}
e^{t/2} & 0\\
0 &  e^{-t/2}
\end{matrix}: t\in \mathbb R \}$$
The matrix $g_t$ acts on a translation surface $\omega$ by stretching along horizontal lines by a factor of $e^{t/2}$ and by contracting along vertical lines by the same factor. This is called Teichmüller geodesic flow.

Let me suggest that you improve your post by adding a few details. For example, your title mentions Theorem 5.3.1, but the body of your post makes no mention of that theorem. Can you explain the connection between the title and the body of your post? Also, you might wish to look at our guidelines for providing context, and on avoiding "no clue" questions.

I suggest you include your definition of the $g_t$-flow and $SL(2,R)$-action. With the definitions that I know, the answer is obvious.

@LeeMosher will do thanks for pointing this out

@MoisheKohan will do thanks for pointing this out

Assume $f$ is invariant under every element of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$. For any point $\omega \in \mathcal{H}$ and any $M \in \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ we have $f(M \cdot \omega) = f(\omega)$. In particular, each $g_t$ of the Teichmüller geodesic flow is a matrix in $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, typically represented by
$$
g_t = \begin{pmatrix} e^{t} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-t} \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Since $g_t \in \mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$, we plug this specific matrix into the invariance condition and get $f(g_t \cdot \omega) = f(\omega)$ for every $t$. Thus $f$ is invariant under $g_t$. The argument does not require additional hypotheses because any subgroup element lies in the full group, so any function invariant under the full group is automatically invariant under its one-parameter subgroups.

Just to confirm, the sl2 action is the action by mobius transformation with coefficients in $\mathbb R$?

Classically, $\mathrm{PSL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ acts on $\mathbb{H}$ via Möbius transformations. For translation surfaces, the $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$-action is linear on plane polygons by applying matrices to $\mathbb{R}^2$ coordinates. This induces an action on abelian or quadratic differentials, with the geodesic flow $(g_t)$ as the diagonal subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$. Thus, it’s a linear action on polygons underlying translation surfaces, corresponding to a natural flow on moduli space, not the classical Möbius action on $\mathbb{H}$.
